# How can i fix the connection of my flutter app to my huawei?

Tags: android, flutter, socketexception, web-api-testing

**After connecting my huawei phone to my pc, I run the flutter app and I get this error in my console:**

> D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe( 3508): Current Activity:false
>   D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe( 3508): not watching, wait.
>   E/        ( 3508): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
>   W/libEGL  ( 3508): EGLNativeWindowType 0x7639517010 disconnect failed
>   D/ViewRootImplMainActivity: surface should not be released
>   I/Choreographer( 3508): Skipped 275 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   W/libEGL  ( 3508): EGLNativeWindowType 0x764275f010 disconnect failed
>   D/AwareBitmapCacher( 3508): handleInit switch not opened pid=3508

**the flutter app on my phone shows this error:**

> Something wrong with message:SocketException:OS Error: Connection refused,errno=111,address=localhost,port=53492

- Any idea of how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to send a request to `localhost` and it fails, because `localhost` on your phone refers to your phone. Change address to `10.0.2.2` to refer to your development machine.

Comment: in my api services class , i have this as my baseUrl now :final String baseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:44382/api"; but still the error appears